# PHP login session and cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies

On my PHP website, users can login and have the possibility to check "Remember me" to set a cookie.

What should I be storing as a `SESSION` variable? The username, hashed password and `user ID`, or only the `user ID`? If I only store the `user ID`, wouldn't it be possible for someone to edit the `SESSION` and change the ID?

What about the `COOKIE`? Should I store only the `user ID`? As far as I know, cookies can be modified by the end user...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems that you don't have a clear vision of sessions and cookies!

No body can change the session contents except your code (beside attacks). So you can store everything (reasonable) like `user id` or `username` that you need to access frequently. in cookies you must store some obfuscated information that you can recognize user later when he/she tries to access your page. so based on cookie content you can regenerate users session (ie. re-login user automatically). Just to note that user CAN change cookies content so it must not be something simple like `user id` for security reason.

I just give you a simple example, it's far from perfect but not so bad! you may need to tailor it to fit your scenario:

here you can create cookie content like this:

```
$salt = substr (md5($password), 0, 2);
$cookie = base64_encode ("$username:" . md5 ($password, $salt));
setcookie ('my-secret-cookie', $cookie);
```

and later to re-login user you do:

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['my-secret-cookie'];
$content = base64_decode ($cookie);
list($username, $hashed_password) = explode (':', $hash);

// here you need to fetch real password from database based on username. ($password)
if (md5($password, substr(md5($password), 0, 2)) == $hashed_password) {
    // you can consider use as logged in
    // do whatever you want :)
}
```

UPDATE:

I wrote [this article](http://boynux.com/consumers-system-trusted-database/) that covers this concept. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ; can you give a best practice for the use of cookies to re-login a user? I can't figure out how I would proceed...

Comment: check update! the code is written on the fly! so if you see typo or bugs I'm sorry for that try to fix it or tell me the problem

Comment: Thanks, it seems a good approach. What do you think of this: http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/ ? Seems excellent to me. But is it obsolete?

Comment: That's not so bad but consider in that solution you need to store the random number he mentioned in DB. It's stronger than my solution as far as you can create really good **RANDOM** number to avoid brute force attack. use your common sense and choose what ever you think is better fits your program context.

Comment: You are using md5 to hide a password. Don't do it, for whatever reason. It's usually best to create a completely random value for this remember-me cookie and store it as an alternative password for the user account. That way it is even more random than the usual password, and nobody can use the value to reverse-engineer the password.

Comment: @Adam There's actually a really useful Gateway that generates true arbitrary alphanumeric sequences. https://api.cloudianos.com/docs#genToken

Answer (score 5):

You should be storing the random session value in the cookie. You definitely should not be storing any information about the user in the cookie itself. You can then check the session id in the cookie on each page load to ensure that (a) the user should have access to that content and (b) that the session ID is valid.

In PHP you can use `session_set_cookie_params` and `session_name` to set the parameters of the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

For who may prefer using cookies (So you can access it long time later even if the browser was closed) this is a safe way to store even rough ID in cookies:

1. Create a new field in users database name it **X**.
2. Generate a cookie to keep the user **ID**.
3. Generate a safe (say long) **RandomString** and keep it in another cookie.
4. Also save that random string in the filed of **X**.
5. In members area check if cookies of **ID** and **RandomString** match the database information.
6. Clear column X when user signs out and generate data for **X** on next login.

To prevent library attack to match that random string, you may also force logout as soon as the check fails or blocking that IP for a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

User cannot edit session variable, these are managed on server.

Session Variable Advantage
1.)Secure
2.)Robust

Session Disadvantage
1.) Short life time, untill session exist ,

session get destroyed
when user close his browser
server restart
session destroyed using  session_destroy();

So session is more secure

Cookie on the other hand let you remember user prefrences

If you use combination of both , then its advantage to your code

```
You can store userid and username in cookie, then verify user identity using its combination.
```

If its not exits then you can login user and keep info in session as well as update cookie.